# How can I add mvc.net to an old vb.net site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

this is my first question. The company I work for uses a pretty large and old vb.net site. We were hoping to integrate mvc.net into the site. I've been following a book "Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework" by Steven Sanderson - and it doesn't seem terrible complicated to merge the 2 systems together.

The breakdown looks like this:

1. Update build file - add GUIDs to  so IDE gives options for mvc files.
2. Add assembly references for mvc.net.
3. enable routing. (I need to be sure it still uses the vb.net routing first, then mvc)
4. Merge web.configs. (Using a new blank mvc.net vb project, also where I got the GUID from)
5. Add whatever folders and start using mvc.

For reference, we currently use .net 3.5, but our operations team tells me 4.0 should be no problem.

The problem I run into is that the GUID from the blank mvc project doesn't work. When I add them to the older project I get "The project type is not supported by this installation." errors. I'm not very familiar with the project types and I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I've tried several combinations to with no success.

Does anyone know how to where I can get or generate the correct GUIDs to get this working? If anyone has done this, are there any other pitfalls I should watch out for? I have the project copied to another branch, so I'm free to make changes without affecting anything else.

Edit:
These are the GUIDs from our main site project:
{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};
{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}

These are the GUIDs from a new mvc4 project (I'm not picky about MVC2-4)
{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};
{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you leave the current code base as it is.

You can start all your new development(new modules) in ASP.Net MVC. You can then just integrate this new module in your application. This way you can keep all the regression in respected code bases.

You will face problem only in case of session. If you are having InProc session then it would be little difficult to share. If it is already OutProc then it is easy.

Comment: Sorry it took forever to your accept answer. After working with my other team members, this is indeed the path we took. Its working well so far.